# Using Application.Current.Dispatcher during tests

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, viewmodel, dispatcher

In a lot of our viewmodels, we have code that looks something like this :

```
void Process()
{
    // do some work
    ...

    // Dispatch some UI notification (purely visual related)
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ...);
}
```

We use `Application.Dispatcher` to ensure it runs on the UI thread, as `Dispatcher.Current` might not be the UI dispatcher.

The reason for dispatching the call is irrelevant and doesn't affect control flow or logic, however, when we test the viewmodel, we obviously have the issue that `Application.Current` is null.

Assuming the code being dispatched has no effect on the test. What to you think is the best way to get around the issue of it being null?

I can think of a few

1. Simply use `Application.Current?.Dispatcher()`. Is this a code smell?
2. Have some kind of mockable `IApplicationDispatcher` that every ViewModel has access to. This gives us the most power, but at the same time, it's annoying to now have an extra constructor parameter for each viewmodel.
3. Ensure tests run with a new application being created on initialise. This is ugly, and would need to be a static application that all UI tests share.

Comment: I'd say using Application.Current.Dispatcher in a view model at all is a "code smell". The view model should not be aware of any view-specific things. Better let the view model update UI-related properties in the same thread in which it was created and make sure a view model instance is created in the UI thread. Perform background tasks by Task.Run or other asynchronous means.

Comment: Is that really any different though? under the hood, the async system is still going to be using the Dispatcher via the SynchronizationContext to dispatch.

Comment: Sure, but you would not have to know that and explicitly care for it in your tests.

Comment: But it would also be massively overkill for us. We just need the dispatch bit, no need for the extra work in making it async.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dispatcher` is usually not required in the view model. This is because the view model should not handle UI elements in general. In other words types that extend `DispatcherObject` should not be referenced outside the view.

When your view model class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` setting a property from a background thread does not require the `Dispatcher`. The binding engine will marshal the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event to the correct dispatcher thread (UI thread).

This does not apply for the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event. You would have to configure the binding engine explicitly to marshal the event to the dispatcher thread by using the [`BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-data-bindingoperations-enablecollectionsynchronization(system-collections-ienumerable-system-object)) method. This way the binding engine will take care to raise the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event on the correct dispatcher thread:

```cs
class ViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<object> BindingSourceCollection { get; }
  private object SyncLock { get; }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.SyncLock = new object();
    this.BindingSourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();    

    // The call must occur on the UI thread.
    // The call must occur before using the collection on a different thread. 
    // The call must occur before attaching the collection to the ItemsControl.
    BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this.BindingSourceCollection, this.SyncLock);
  }
}
```

This way the most common uses of the `Dispatcher` in the view model (set property that is a binding source and add item to a collection that is a binding source) are eliminated. This removes the static Singleton reference from your code to enable full testability.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `IApplicationDispatcher` interface (option 2). It doesn't necessarily have to be a constructor parameter. You could for example add it as a property on the base view model class and set it as needed in your tests.

Just make sure to set the property to a wrapper around `Application.Current.Dispatcher` in your real app.

Calling static methods in your view models doesn't make them very unit test friendly I am afraid.

Checking for null references (option 1) is not a code smell. You should probably do this as well.